# Centos 7/Gnome Applications menu items don't respond

Tags: centos, gnome, menu

I have CentOS 7 installed with gnome. After some uptime, no items under the 'Applications' menu respond.* I can open the menus and submenus and hover over items with the mouse pointer. They will highlight correctly, but they do not respond to clicks.

The items also do not respond to keyboard navigation where I can still use the arrow keys to move around the menus and highlight items, but hitting `enter` etc. does not launch the application/tool highlighted.

Restarting the machine helps, but that seems a heavy handed solution to the problem.

*With the exception of the 'Activities Overview' item

Comment: Does clicking on anything else other than _Applications_ works? Like _Places_ or desktop icons or applications already opened.

Comment: Yes, the whole desktop is fully functional, the places menu and all of its items are selectable.

Comment: The same happens to me (i regret having switched to Centos from Debian). I tried `gnome-shell --replace`, the Application menu still unclickable and the following message is printed to the terminal:

Comment: JS ERROR: !!! Exception was: Error: can't convert event.get_time() to an integer
    JS ERROR: !!! message = '"can't convert event.get_time() to an integer"'
   JS ERROR: !!! fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js"'
   JS ERROR: !!! lineNumber = '77'
   JS ERROR: !!! stack = '"([object GObject_Union])@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js:77

Comment: Is that to say Gnome desktops are implemented in Java...?

Comment: Its JavaScript, not Java, but yes, that's how GNOME 3 extensions work.  Sounds like a bug in the 'apps-menu' gnome extension.  Seems that a [bug has been filed about it](https://github.com/gcampax/gnome-shell-extensions/issues/7).

Answer (score 7):

This is a known issue.  See here:

[apps-menu: Exception: can't convert event.get_time() to an integer #7](https://github.com/gcampax/gnome-shell-extensions/issues/7)

A fix is to change line 77 of `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js`

from:

```
this._app.open_new_window(event.get_time());
```

to:

```
this._app.open_new_window(-1);
```

Comment: A more important question then is why did the code call for this in the first place? Is it just an overflow on the get_time() return type not fitting into an integer after enough up-time? Who is responsible for maintaining that code?